# Unable to add data in to table mysql

Tags: php, mysql

```
$insert_query = "Asset Addition (server_name, phy_ip, nat_ip, server_model) values ('$server_name','$phy_ip','$nat_ip','$server_model')";

if(mysqli_query($con, $insert_query))
```

Do you think there is an issue with the syntax here?

Comment: `Asset Addition` what's that?

Comment: `Do you think there is an issue with the syntax here?`....Do you? What do your errors tell you?

Comment: if Asset Addition is a table then just use it by insert query?

Comment: I think there is some thing wrong, however i am not seeing any errors

Comment: `Addition` means "to add" in French, so you can't use that. MySQL/php etc. are all English-based syntax. So you need `INSERT INTO`.

Comment: seems you missing the  INSERT table_name  in your code  ..  (in English  )  .. in french INSERT nome_de_tableau

Comment: @JustBaron why are you undoing my edit from earlier? https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/46056416/2 - the clarity is more readable.

Comment: table name is sites. I tried using INSERT INTO, however i think i am not sure how to get it to work.

Comment: As others have said, you have definitely got syntax errors. I think you maybe need to study basic SQL syntax before continuing. Check the output of `mysqli_error()` after you run your query, it will show you any errors from the database. Also it would appear that your code is vulnerable to SQL injection attacks. You should use parameterised queries and prepared statements to help prevent attackers from compromising your database by using malicious input values. http://bobby-tables.com/ gives an explanation of the risks, as well as some examples of how to write your queries safely using mysqli.

Comment: $insert_query = "INSERT INTO sites(server_name, phy_ip, nat_ip, server_model) VALUES ('$server_name','$phy_ip','$nat_ip','$server_model')";
  
  if(mysqli_query($con, $insert_query)){

Comment: now that doesnt work either, Yes I am new to this. please help me. Thank you

Comment: @Fred-ii- Wasn't undoing your edit, I think we were editing at the same time and you beat me to the punch.

Comment: @JustBaron ah ok :-) I was going to make it one line also as per the OP's code, but put the `VALUES` etc. onto a second line.

Comment: Well, there isn't much I can add to my answer below. You will need to take it from here @BalajiDeshpande

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> "Do you think there is an issue with the syntax here?"

Yes, as I said in comments; syntax is English-based.

You need to use: `INSERT INTO your_table` and replacing with your table's actual name.

Your code also is open to an sql injection, use a prepared statement.

- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement

and `mysqli_error($con)` on the query.

Edit: Now seeing more comments, make sure you did successfully connect to your database and using the same MySQL API, and that all variables contain value and running off a webserver with PHP/MySQL installed and running.

Reference(s):

- http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysqli-connect.php
- http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php

Example:

```
if(mysqli_query($con, $insert_query)) {
    echo "Success";
} else {
    echo "Error: " . mysqli_error($con);
}
```

Should this also fail, then you may also be inserting characters that MySQL is complaining about, such as an apostrophe and is seeing it as an sql injection.

Therefore you will need to escape that data, to which you should be doing in any case.

Again; use a prepared statement.

You need to make sure that the column types/lengths can also accomodate the incoming data. That could fail silently.

Comment: Thank you Fred, It worked. Awesome!!!

Comment: I had an extra field in the data base, which was not letting it add. your error idetification mechanism helped me find that out.

Comment: @BalajiDeshpande You're most welcome, *cheers*. If you want to mark the question as being solved, consider accepting the answer. This informs everyone that a solution was found, and welcome to Stack Overflow.